# Efficient way to count rows with mulit category columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with head `uid, col1, col2`, where `col1` has `k1` unique value(e.g `a,b,c`),`col2` has `k2` unique value(e.g. "low", "high"). After grouping by `uid`, if I want to count the number of being `col1=='a'`, I would do this

```
df.groupby("uid")['col1'].apply(lambda group: sum(group=='a')).reset_index(name="a_cnt")
```

If I want to count the number of being `col1=='a' and col2='low'`, I would do this

```
df.groupby("uid")['col1', 'col2'].apply(lambda group: sum((group['col1']=='a') & (group['col2']=='low'))).reset_index(name="a_low_cnt")
```

Any other efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `mask`, add to DataFrame with convert to numbers by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last aggregate `sum` for improve performance:

```
#first mask
#m = (df['col1']=='a')

#second mask
m = (df['col1']=='a') & (df['col2']=='low')

df = df.assign(new = m.astype(int)).groupby("uid")['new'].sum()
```

Or:

```
df = df.assign(new = m.view('i1')).groupby("uid")['new'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks. In my second part of code, should I use `df.groupby('uid')['col1','col2']` or  `df.groupby('uid')[['col1','col2']]`?They both give me same result, any difference between them?